# android database sql insert data and display

Tags: android

I am following some tutorials about sqlite database on android. However when i try to insert some values to the database i got logcat error.

the database:

```
todo methods

    /*
     * Creating a todo
     */
    public long createToDo(Todo todo, long[] tag_ids) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TODO, todo.getNote());
        values.put(KEY_STATUS, todo.getStatus());
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());
        // insert row
        long todo_id = db.insert(TABLE_TODO, null, values);
        // insert tag_ids
        for (long tag_id : tag_ids) {
            createTodoTag(todo_id, tag_id);
        }
        return todo_id;
    }
    /*
     * get single todo
     */
    public Todo getTodo(long todo_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TODO + " WHERE "
                + KEY_ID + " = " + todo_id;
        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();
        Todo td = new Todo();
        td.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
        td.setNote((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TODO))));
        td.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
        return td;
    }
    /**
     * getting all todos
     * */
    public List<Todo> getAllToDos() {
        List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TODO;
        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Todo td = new Todo();
                td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
                td.setNote((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TODO))));
            td.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
                // adding to todo list
                todos.add(td);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return todos;
    }
    /**
     * getting all todos under single tag
     * */
    public List<Todo> getAllToDosByTag(String tag_name) {
        List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TODO + " td, "
                + TABLE_TAG + " tg, " + TABLE_TODO_TAG + " tt WHERE tg."
                + KEY_TAG_NAME + " = '" + tag_name + "'" + " AND tg." KEY_ID
                + " = " + "tt." + KEY_TAG_ID + " AND td." + KEY_ID + " = "
                + "tt." + KEY_TODO_ID;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Todo td = new Todo();
                td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
                td.setNote((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TODO))));
             td.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
                // adding to todo list
                todos.add(td);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return todos;
    }
    /*
     * getting todo count
     */
    public int getToDoCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TODO;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        // return count
        return count;
    }
    /*
     * Updating a todo
     */
    public int updateToDo(Todo todo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TODO, todo.getNote());
        values.put(KEY_STATUS, todo.getStatus());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_TODO, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(todo.getId()) });
    } 
    /*
     * Deleting a todo
     */
    public void deleteToDo(long tado_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_TODO, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(tado_id) });
    }
        // closing database
public void closeDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}
```

the input:

```
// Creating ToDos
    Todo todo1 = new Todo("iPhone 5S", 0);
    Todo todo2 = new Todo("Galaxy Note II", 0);
    Todo todo3 = new Todo("Whiteboard", 0);

    Todo todo4 = new Todo("Riddick", 0);
    Todo todo5 = new Todo("Prisoners", 0);
    Todo todo6 = new Todo("The Croods", 0);
    Todo todo7 = new Todo("Insidious: Chapter 2", 0);

    Todo todo8 = new Todo("Don't forget to call MOM", 0);
    Todo todo9 = new Todo("Collect money from John", 0);

    Todo todo10 = new Todo("Post new Article", 0);
    Todo todo11 = new Todo("Take database backup", 0);

    // Inserting todos in db
    // Inserting todos under "Shopping" Tag
    long todo1_id = db.createToDo(todo1, new long[] { tag1_id });
    long todo2_id = db.createToDo(todo2, new long[] { tag1_id });
    long todo3_id = db.createToDo(todo3, new long[] { tag1_id });

    // Inserting todos under "Watchlist" Tag
    long todo4_id = db.createToDo(todo4, new long[] { tag3_id });
    long todo5_id = db.createToDo(todo5, new long[] { tag3_id });
    long todo6_id = db.createToDo(todo6, new long[] { tag3_id });
    long todo7_id = db.createToDo(todo7, new long[] { tag3_id });

    // Inserting todos under "Important" Tag
    long todo8_id = db.createToDo(todo8, new long[] { tag2_id });
    long todo9_id = db.createToDo(todo9, new long[] { tag2_id });

    // Inserting todos under "Androidhive" Tag
    long todo10_id = db.createToDo(todo10, new long[] { tag4_id });
    long todo11_id = db.createToDo(todo11, new long[] { tag4_id });

    Log.e("Todo Count", "Todo count: " + db.getToDoCount());


// Getting all Todos
    Log.d("Get Todos", "Getting All ToDos");

    List<Todo> allToDos = db.getAllToDos();
    for (Todo todo : allToDos) {
        Log.d("ToDo", todo.getNote());
    }
```

// Don't forget to close database connection
        db.closeDB();

logcat error:

```
    04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273): Error inserting id=31 ER_tenor=12 ER_rate=12.1 Used_or_New=Baru
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.helper.DatabaseHelper.createEntryEffectiveRate(DatabaseHelper.java:405)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 16:14:49.582: E/Database(273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273): Error inserting id=32 ER_tenor=24 ER_rate=12.2 Used_or_New=Baru
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.helper.DatabaseHelper.createEntryEffectiveRate(DatabaseHelper.java:405)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:97)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 16:14:49.592: E/Database(273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273): Error inserting id=33 ER_tenor=36 ER_rate=12.3 Used_or_New=Baru
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.helper.DatabaseHelper.createEntryEffectiveRate(DatabaseHelper.java:405)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:98)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 16:14:49.602: E/Database(273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273): Error inserting id=34 ER_tenor=48 ER_rate=12.4 Used_or_New=Baru
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.helper.DatabaseHelper.createEntryEffectiveRate(DatabaseHelper.java:405)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:99)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 16:14:49.612: E/Database(273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273): Error inserting id=35 ER_tenor=60 ER_rate=12.5 Used_or_New=Baru
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.helper.DatabaseHelper.createEntryEffectiveRate(DatabaseHelper.java:405)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 16:14:49.622: E/Database(273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273): Error inserting id=36 ER_tenor=12 ER_rate=12.6 Used_or_New=Bekas
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.helper.DatabaseHelper.createEntryEffectiveRate(DatabaseHelper.java:405)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 16:14:49.642: E/Database(273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273): Error inserting id=37 ER_tenor=24 ER_rate=12.7 Used_or_New=Bekas
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.helper.DatabaseHelper.createEntryEffectiveRate(DatabaseHelper.java:405)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at info.androidhive.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 16:14:49.652: E/Database(273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i have more tables that i havent mentioned,

the code:

```
//ER methods
    public long createEntryEffectiveRate(EntryEffectiveRate EER, long[] as_ids) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valuesER = new ContentValues();
        valuesER.put(KEY_ID, EER.getERId());
        valuesER.put(KEY_ER_USEDORNEW, EER.getERKondisi());
        valuesER.put(KEY_ER_TENOR, EER.getERTenor());
        valuesER.put(KEY_ER_RATE, EER.getERrate());
        //values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        // insert row
        long er_id = db.insert(TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE, null, valuesER);

        // insert tag_ids
        //for (long as_id : as_ids) {
    //      createTodoTag(er_id, as_id);
        //}

        return er_id;
    }

    //get er
    public EntryEffectiveRate getEntryEffectiveRate(long er_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE + " WHERE "
                + KEY_ID + " = " + er_id;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();

        EntryEffectiveRate ergt = new EntryEffectiveRate();
        ergt.setERId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
        ergt.setERKondisi(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_USEDORNEW)));
        ergt.setERTenor(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_TENOR)));
        ergt.setERRate(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_RATE)));
        //ergt.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));

        return ergt;
    }
    //getting all ER
    public List<EntryEffectiveRate> getAllEffectiveRates() {
        List<EntryEffectiveRate> EffectiveRates = new ArrayList<EntryEffectiveRate>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                EntryEffectiveRate ergt = new EntryEffectiveRate();
                ergt.setERId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                ergt.setERKondisi(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_USEDORNEW)));
                ergt.setERTenor(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_TENOR)));
                ergt.setERRate(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_RATE)));

                // adding to todo list
                EffectiveRates.add(ergt);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return EffectiveRates;
    }

    //get er count
    public int getEntryEffectiveRateCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return count;
    }

    /*
     * Updating a todo
     */
    public int updateEntryEffectiveRate(EntryEffectiveRate er) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, er.getERId());
        values.put(KEY_ER_USEDORNEW, er.getERKondisi());
        values.put(KEY_ER_TENOR, er.getERTenor());
        values.put(KEY_ER_RATE, er.getERrate());
        //values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(er.getERId()) });
    }
    //
    public void deleteEntryEffectiveRate(long er_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(er_id) });
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    the inserted values:


        EntryEffectiveRate er_id = new EntryEffectiveRate(31, "Baru", 12, 12.1);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id1 = new EntryEffectiveRate(32, "Baru", 24, 12.2);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id2 = new EntryEffectiveRate(33, "Baru", 36, 12.3);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id3 = new EntryEffectiveRate(34, "Baru", 48, 12.4);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id4 = new EntryEffectiveRate(35, "Baru", 60, 12.5);

        EntryEffectiveRate er_id5 = new EntryEffectiveRate(36, "Bekas", 12,
                12.6);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id6 = new EntryEffectiveRate(37, "Bekas", 24,
                12.7);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id7 = new EntryEffectiveRate(38, "Bekas", 36,
                12.8);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id8 = new EntryEffectiveRate(39, "Bekas", 48,
                12.9);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id9 = new EntryEffectiveRate(40, "Bekas", 60,
                12.10);

        long er = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id, null);
        long er1 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id1, null);
        long er2 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id2, null);
        long er3 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id3, null);
        long er4 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id4, null);
        long er5 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id5, null);
        long er6 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id6, null);
        long er7 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id7, null);
        long er8 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id8, null);
        long er9 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id9, null);
        Log.d("Effectiverate Count", " EffectiverateCount: "
                + db.getAllEffectiveRates().size());
// getting all ER
        Log.d("Get ER", "GEtting All ER");

        List<EntryEffectiveRate> allEffectiveRate = db.getAllEffectiveRates();
        for (EntryEffectiveRate ER : allEffectiveRate) {
            Log.d("ER_ids", String.valueOf(ER.getERId()));
            Log.d("ER_rates", ER.getERKondisi());
            Log.d("ER_tenors", String.valueOf(ER.getERTenor()));
            Log.d("ER_rates", String.valueOf(ER.getERrate()));
        }
```

Comment: Just a friendly advice, you should always do INSERT,QUERY,UPDATE, etc. in an asyntask and you always close and set the cursor to null after you iterated it.

Comment: close the cursor before returning todos in **getAllToDosByTag** method

Comment: @cesztoszule do you have some references, example that implement that

Comment: Can I know in which line are you getting the error.

Comment: @AmrutBidri after i put the cursor, the logcat seems pretty clear at the first time run then when i re-run it gives this error dozen times whenever the insert called: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Comment: @Kesh1234 unfortunatly there is no "caused by"  at the logcat. what i know it happens because i havent close the cursor.

Comment: @georgesamuel closing a cursor is a good practice to avoid memory leaks, but its not mandatory and your application will not crash for that.

Comment: What is line number 53?

Comment: just change this line `return todos;` to  `c.close(); return todos;` in **getAllToDosByTag** method

Comment: @AmrutBidri i did but on the second time i run the app the logcat give me errors again about constraint failed. It works on the 1st time after i put the cursor.close();

Comment: post the second logcat

Comment: @Kesh1234 empty space both on activity and database.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you tell in which method are you getting the error by seeing the query of logcat

Comment: @Kesh1234 getAllTodoLists, all the methods about getlist

Comment: In all getTodo methods close the cursor before the return statement and run the app again and check what will you get.

Comment: Its like re-inserting all the values whenever i run the app. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is KEY_ID which defined as integer primary key autoincrement this probably means the insert statement is violating a constraint in the new table. Could be a primary key constraint, a unique constraint, a foreign key constraint. So i make more 2 id's for each table and set them to `INTEGER`
And thanks to Kesh1234,cesztoszule, Amrut Bidri for helping me figuring out the solution.

The working code:

The databasehelper code

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Logcat tag
    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Rates";

    // Table Names

    public static final String KEY_ER_ID = "er_id";
    public static final String KEY_ER_USEDORNEW = "Used_or_New";
    public static final String KEY_ER_TENOR = "ER_tenor";
    public static final String KEY_ER_RATE = "ER_rate";
    // Asuransi rate
    public static final String KEY_AS_ID = "as_id";
    public static final String KEY_AS_REGIONAL = "regional";
    public static final String KEY_AS_TENOR = "AS_tenor";
    public static final String KEY_AS_TLO = "TLO";
    public static final String KEY_AS_COMPREHENSIVE = "Comprehensive";
    public static final String KEY_AS_COMBINE = "Combine";

    public static final String TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE = "effective_rate";
    public static final String TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE = "asuransi_rate";

    // Common column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    // Table Create Statements

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE + " (" + KEY_AS_ID
            + " INTEGER, " + KEY_AS_REGIONAL
            + " INTEGER, " + KEY_AS_TENOR + " INTEGER," + KEY_AS_TLO
            + " REAL," + KEY_AS_COMPREHENSIVE + " REAL,"
            + KEY_AS_COMBINE + " REAL" +")"; 

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE + " ("
            + KEY_ER_ID + " INTEGER, "
            + KEY_ER_USEDORNEW + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ER_TENOR
            + " INTEGER," + KEY_ER_RATE + " REAL"+ ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
    //ER methods
    public long createEntryEffectiveRate(EntryEffectiveRate EER/*, long[] as_ids*/) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valuesER = new ContentValues();
        valuesER.put(KEY_ER_ID, EER.getERId());
        valuesER.put(KEY_ER_USEDORNEW, EER.getERKondisi());
        valuesER.put(KEY_ER_TENOR, EER.getERTenor());
        valuesER.put(KEY_ER_RATE, EER.getERrate());
        //values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        // insert row
        long er_id = db.insert(TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE, null, valuesER);

        return er_id;
    }

    //get er
    public EntryEffectiveRate getEntryEffectiveRate(long er_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE + " WHERE "
                + KEY_ER_ID + " = " + er_id;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();

        EntryEffectiveRate ergt = new EntryEffectiveRate();
        ergt.setERId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_ID)));
        ergt.setERKondisi(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_USEDORNEW)));
        ergt.setERTenor(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_TENOR)));
        ergt.setERRate(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_RATE)));
        //ergt.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));

        c.close();
        return ergt;
    }
    //getting all ER
    public List<EntryEffectiveRate> getAllEffectiveRates() {
        List<EntryEffectiveRate> EffectiveRates = new ArrayList<EntryEffectiveRate>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                EntryEffectiveRate ergt = new EntryEffectiveRate();
                ergt.setERId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_ID)));
                ergt.setERKondisi(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_USEDORNEW)));
                ergt.setERTenor(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_TENOR)));
                ergt.setERRate(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ER_RATE)));

                // add
                EffectiveRates.add(ergt);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return EffectiveRates;
    }

    //get er count
    public int getEntryEffectiveRateCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return count;
    }

    /*
     * Updating a todo
     */
    public int updateEntryEffectiveRate(EntryEffectiveRate er) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ER_ID, er.getERId());
        values.put(KEY_ER_USEDORNEW, er.getERKondisi());
        values.put(KEY_ER_TENOR, er.getERTenor());
        values.put(KEY_ER_RATE, er.getERrate());
        //values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE, values, KEY_ER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(er.getERId()) });
    }
    //
    public void deleteEntryEffectiveRate(long er_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_EFFECTIVE_RATE, KEY_ER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(er_id) });
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public long createEntryAsuransiRate(EntryAsuransiRate EAR/*, long[] as_ids*/) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valuesAS = new ContentValues();
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_ID, EAR.getASId());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_REGIONAL, EAR.getASzona());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_TENOR, EAR.getAStenor());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_TLO, EAR.getAStlo());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_COMPREHENSIVE, EAR.getAScomp());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_COMBINE, EAR.getAScomb());
        //values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        // insert row
        long er_id = db.insert(TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE, null, valuesAS);

        return er_id;
    }

    //get er
    public EntryAsuransiRate getEntryAsuransiRate(long as_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE + " WHERE "
                + KEY_AS_ID + " = " + as_id;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();

        EntryAsuransiRate asgt = new EntryAsuransiRate();
        asgt.setASId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_ID)));
        asgt.setASzona(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_REGIONAL)));
        asgt.setAStenor(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_TENOR)));
        asgt.setAStlo(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_TLO)));
        asgt.setAScomp(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_COMPREHENSIVE)));
        asgt.setAScomb(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_COMBINE)));
        //ergt.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
        c.close();
        return asgt;
    }
    //getting all ER
    public List<EntryAsuransiRate> getAllAsuransiRates() {
        List<EntryAsuransiRate> AsuransiRates = new ArrayList<EntryAsuransiRate>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                EntryAsuransiRate asgt = new EntryAsuransiRate();
                asgt.setASId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_ID)));
                asgt.setASzona(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_REGIONAL)));
                asgt.setAStenor(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_TENOR)));
                asgt.setAStlo(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_TLO)));
                asgt.setAScomp(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_COMPREHENSIVE)));
                asgt.setAScomb(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AS_COMBINE)));
                // add
                AsuransiRates.add(asgt);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return AsuransiRates;
    }

    //get er count
    public int getEntryAsuransiRateCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return count;
    }

    /*
     * Updating a todo
     */
    public int updateEntryAsuransiRate(EntryAsuransiRate EAR) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valuesAS = new ContentValues();
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_ID, EAR.getASId());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_REGIONAL, EAR.getASzona());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_TENOR, EAR.getAStenor());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_TLO, EAR.getAStlo());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_COMPREHENSIVE, EAR.getAScomp());
        valuesAS.put(KEY_AS_COMBINE, EAR.getAScomb());
        //values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE, valuesAS, KEY_AS_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(EAR.getASId()) });
    }
    //
    public void deleteEntryAsuransiRate(long as_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_ASURANSI_RATE, KEY_AS_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(as_id) });
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // closing database
    public void closeDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }

    /**
     * get datetime
     * */
    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

the main activity that will insert the values:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Database Helper
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());


        EntryEffectiveRate er_id = new EntryEffectiveRate(1, "Baru", 12, 12.1);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id1 = new EntryEffectiveRate(2, "Baru", 24, 12.2);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id2 = new EntryEffectiveRate(3, "Baru", 36, 12.3);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id3 = new EntryEffectiveRate(4, "Baru", 48, 12.4);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id4 = new EntryEffectiveRate(5, "Baru", 60, 12.5);

        EntryEffectiveRate er_id5 = new EntryEffectiveRate(6, "Bekas", 12,
                12.6);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id6 = new EntryEffectiveRate(7, "Bekas", 24,
                12.7);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id7 = new EntryEffectiveRate(8, "Bekas", 36,
                12.8);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id8 = new EntryEffectiveRate(9, "Bekas", 48,
                12.9);
        EntryEffectiveRate er_id9 = new EntryEffectiveRate(10, "Bekas", 60,
                12.10);

        long er = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id);
        long er1 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id1);
        long er2 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id2);
        long er3 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id3);
        long er4 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id4);

        long er5 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id5);
        long er6 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id6);
        long er7 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id7);
        long er8 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id8);
        long er9 = db.createEntryEffectiveRate(er_id9);

        Log.d("Effectiverate Count", " EffectiverateCount: "
                + db.getAllEffectiveRates().size());

        EntryAsuransiRate as = new EntryAsuransiRate(1, 1, 12, 0.07, 2.07,
                2.14);
        EntryAsuransiRate as1 = new EntryAsuransiRate(2, 1, 24, 0.08, 2.06,
                2.15);
        EntryAsuransiRate as2 = new EntryAsuransiRate(3, 1, 36, 0.09, 2.05,
                2.16);
        EntryAsuransiRate as3 = new EntryAsuransiRate(4, 1, 48, 0.10, 2.04,
                2.17);
        EntryAsuransiRate as4 = new EntryAsuransiRate(5, 1, 60, 0.11, 2.03,
                2.18);

        EntryAsuransiRate as5 = new EntryAsuransiRate(6, 2, 12, 0.12, 2.02,
                2.19);
        EntryAsuransiRate as6 = new EntryAsuransiRate(7, 2, 24, 0.13, 2.01,
                2.20);
        EntryAsuransiRate as7 = new EntryAsuransiRate(8, 2, 36, 0.14, 2.00,
                2.21);
        EntryAsuransiRate as8 = new EntryAsuransiRate(9, 2, 48, 0.15, 1.99,
                2.22);
        EntryAsuransiRate as9 = new EntryAsuransiRate(10, 2, 60, 0.16, 1.98,
                2.23);

        EntryAsuransiRate as10 = new EntryAsuransiRate(11, 3, 12, 0.17, 1.97,
                2.24);
        EntryAsuransiRate as11 = new EntryAsuransiRate(12, 3, 24, 0.18, 1.96,
                2.25);
        EntryAsuransiRate as12 = new EntryAsuransiRate(13, 3, 36, 0.19, 1.95,
                2.26);
        EntryAsuransiRate as13 = new EntryAsuransiRate(14, 3, 48, 0.20, 1.94,
                2.27);
        EntryAsuransiRate as14 = new EntryAsuransiRate(15, 3, 60, 0.21, 1.93,
                2.28);

        long as_id = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as);
        long as_id1 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as1);
        long as_id2 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as2);
        long as_id3 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as3);
        long as_id4 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as4);

        long as_id5 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as5);
        long as_id6 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as6);
        long as_id7 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as7);
        long as_id8 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as8);
        long as_id9 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as9);

        long as_id10 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as10);
        long as_id11 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as11);
        long as_id12 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as12);
        long as_id13 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as13);
        long as_id14 = db.createEntryAsuransiRate(as14);

        Log.d("Asuransirate Count", " AsuransirateCount: "
                + db.getAllAsuransiRates().size());

        // getting all ER
        Log.d("Get ER", "GEtting All ER");

        List<EntryEffectiveRate> allEffectiveRate = db.getAllEffectiveRates();
        for (EntryEffectiveRate ER : allEffectiveRate) {
            Log.d("ER_ids", String.valueOf(ER.getERId()));
            Log.d("ER_rates", ER.getERKondisi());
            Log.d("ER_tenors", String.valueOf(ER.getERTenor()));
            Log.d("ER_rates", String.valueOf(ER.getERrate()));
        }

        // getting all AS
        Log.d("Get AS", "GEtting All AS");

        List<EntryAsuransiRate> allAsuransiRate = db.getAllAsuransiRates();
        for (EntryAsuransiRate AS : allAsuransiRate) {
            Log.d("AS_ids", String.valueOf(AS.getASId()));
            Log.d("AS_tenors", String.valueOf(AS.getAStenor()));
            Log.d("AS_tlos", String.valueOf(AS.getAStlo()));
            Log.d("AS_comps", String.valueOf(AS.getAScomp()));
            Log.d("AS_combs", String.valueOf(AS.getAScomb()));
        }


        // Don't forget to close database connection
        db.closeDB();

    }
}
```

and the model classes:

```
public class EntryAsuransiRate {

    int as_id;
    int ASzona;
    int AStenor;
    double AStlo;
    double AScomp;
    double AScomb;

    // String created_at;

    // constructors
    public EntryAsuransiRate() {
    }

    public EntryAsuransiRate(int ASzona, int AStenor, double AStlo,
            double AScomp, double AScomb) {
        this.ASzona = ASzona;
        this.AStenor = AStenor;
        this.AStlo = AStlo;
        this.AScomp = AScomp;
        this.AScomb = AScomb;
    }

    public EntryAsuransiRate(int as_id, int ASzona, int AStenor, double AStlo,
            double AScomp, double AScomb) {
        this.as_id = as_id;
        this.ASzona = ASzona;
        this.AStenor = AStenor;
        this.AStlo = AStlo;
        this.AScomp = AScomp;
        this.AScomb = AScomb;
    }

    // setters
    public void setASId(int as_id) {
        this.as_id = as_id;
    }

    public void setASzona(int ASzona) {
        this.ASzona = ASzona;
    }

    public void setAStenor(int AStenor) {
        this.AStenor = AStenor;
    }

    public void setAStlo(double AStlo) {
        this.AStlo = AStlo;
    }

    public void setAScomp(double AScomp) {
        this.AScomp = AScomp;
    }

    public void setAScomb(double AScomb) {
        this.AScomb = AScomb;
    }


    // public void setCreatedAt(String created_at){
    // this.created_at = created_at;
    // }

    // getters
    public long getASId() {
        return this.as_id;
    }

    public int getASzona() {
        return this.ASzona;
    }

    public int getAStenor() {
        return this.AStenor;
    }

    public double getAStlo() {
        return this.AStlo;
    }

    public double getAScomp() {
        return this.AScomp;
    }

    public double getAScomb() {
        return this.AScomb;
    }
}
```

another model:

```
public class EntryEffectiveRate {

    int er_id;
    String ERkondisi;
    int ERtenor;
    double ERrate;
    //String created_at;

    // constructors
    public EntryEffectiveRate() {
    }

    public EntryEffectiveRate(String ERkondisi, int ERtenor, double ERrate) {
        this.ERkondisi = ERkondisi;
        this.ERtenor = ERtenor;
        this.ERrate = ERrate;
    }

    public EntryEffectiveRate(int er_id, String ERkondisi, int ERtenor, double ERrate) {
        this.er_id = er_id;
        this.ERkondisi = ERkondisi;
        this.ERtenor = ERtenor;
        this.ERrate = ERrate;
    }

    // setters
    public void setERId(int er_id) {
        this.er_id = er_id;
    }

    public void setERKondisi(String ERkondisi) {
        this.ERkondisi = ERkondisi;
    }

    public void setERTenor(int ERtenor) {
        this.ERtenor = ERtenor;
    }

    public void setERRate(double ERrate){
        this.ERrate = ERrate;
    }

    //public void setCreatedAt(String created_at){
    //  this.created_at = created_at;
    //}

    // getters
    public long getERId() {
        return this.er_id;
    }

    public String getERKondisi() {
        return this.ERkondisi;
    }

    public int getERTenor() {
        return this.ERtenor;
    }
    public double getERrate(){
        return this.ERrate;
    }
}
```

Its working fine the result will be appear in logcat like this:

```
04-02 13:00:19.758: E/DatabaseHelper(360): SELECT  * FROM effective_rate
04-02 13:00:19.779: D/Effectiverate Count(360):  EffectiverateCount: 20
04-02 13:00:21.068: E/DatabaseHelper(360): SELECT  * FROM asuransi_rate
04-02 13:00:21.079: D/Asuransirate Count(360):  AsuransirateCount: 30
04-02 13:00:21.079: D/Get ER(360): GEtting All ER
04-02 13:00:21.089: E/DatabaseHelper(360): SELECT  * FROM effective_rate
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_ids(360): 1
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_rates(360): Baru
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_tenors(360): 12
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_rates(360): 12.1
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_ids(360): 2
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_rates(360): Baru
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_tenors(360): 24
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_rates(360): 12.2
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_ids(360): 3
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_rates(360): Baru
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_tenors(360): 36
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_rates(360): 12.3
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_ids(360): 4
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_rates(360): Baru
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_tenors(360): 48
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_rates(360): 12.4
04-02 13:00:21.099: D/ER_ids(360): 5
04-02 13:00:21.109: D/ER_rates(360): Baru
04-02 13:00:21.109: D/ER_tenors(360): 60
04-02 13:00:21.119: D/ER_rates(360): 12.5
04-02 13:00:21.119: D/ER_ids(360): 6
04-02 13:00:21.119: D/ER_rates(360): Bekas
04-02 13:00:21.119: D/ER_tenors(360): 12
04-02 13:00:21.119: D/ER_rates(360): 12.6
04-02 13:00:21.119: D/ER_ids(360): 7
04-02 13:00:21.129: D/ER_rates(360): Bekas
04-02 13:00:21.129: D/ER_tenors(360): 24
04-02 13:00:21.129: D/ER_rates(360): 12.7
04-02 13:00:21.129: D/ER_ids(360): 8
04-02 13:00:21.129: D/ER_rates(360): Bekas
04-02 13:00:21.129: D/ER_tenors(360): 36
04-02 13:00:21.129: D/ER_rates(360): 12.8
04-02 13:00:21.139: D/ER_ids(360): 9
04-02 13:00:21.139: D/ER_rates(360): Bekas
04-02 13:00:21.139: D/ER_tenors(360): 48
04-02 13:00:21.139: D/ER_rates(360): 12.9
04-02 13:00:21.139: D/ER_ids(360): 10
04-02 13:00:21.149: D/ER_rates(360): Bekas
04-02 13:00:21.149: D/ER_tenors(360): 60
04-02 13:00:21.149: D/ER_rates(360): 12.1
04-02 13:00:21.188: D/Get AS(360): GEtting All AS
04-02 13:00:21.188: E/DatabaseHelper(360): SELECT  * FROM asuransi_rate
04-02 13:00:21.399: D/AS_ids(360): 1
04-02 13:00:21.399: D/AS_tenors(360): 12
04-02 13:00:21.399: D/AS_tlos(360): 0.07
04-02 13:00:21.399: D/AS_comps(360): 2.07
04-02 13:00:21.408: D/AS_combs(360): 2.14
.
.
.
04-02 13:00:21.509: D/AS_ids(360): 15
04-02 13:00:21.509: D/AS_tenors(360): 60
04-02 13:00:21.519: D/AS_tlos(360): 0.21
04-02 13:00:21.519: D/AS_comps(360): 1.93
04-02 13:00:21.519: D/AS_combs(360): 2.28
```

due to body limit characters i shorten it